# iPhone multi-touch coordinates

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

I am making an iphone app that uses two fingers to place and scale a platform. I need to find the x & y coordinates of BOTH of these touches. How would I go about this. thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go through [`Gesture Recognizers`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html). Gesture Recognizers are a better approach to `touchesBegan:` and its siblings if you are developing for `iOS 3.2` and later. For the purpose of scaling, you can look at [`UIPinchGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Also, remember to enable multitouch by setting the view's `multipleTouchEnabled` to `YES`.

Answer (score 2):

check touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded in your UIView subclass.
This is explained in the Apple docs.